# Intel PIN: How to log the value of the fs and gs registers at every instruction?

Tags: x86, pintool, register, segmentation, amd64

I modified the pinatrace pintool example and managed to log all values of the "regular" registers:

```
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
 ...
 // Instrument REGISTER writes using a predicated call, i.e.
 // the call happens iff the register store will be actually executed
 UINT32 maxNumWRegs;
 maxNumWRegs = INS_MaxNumWRegs(ins);
 for (UINT32 i=0; i<maxNumWRegs; i++)
 {
     // --> BEFORE
     INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
        ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)SaveRegWrite,
        IARG_INST_PTR,
        IARG_UINT32,
        INS_RegW(ins, i),
        IARG_END);
    
    if (INS_HasFallThrough(ins))
    {
        // --> AFTER
        INS_InsertCall(
            ins, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)LogRegWrite,
            IARG_INST_PTR,
            IARG_UINT32,
            INS_RegW(ins, i),
            IARG_CONTEXT, // to access the register value
            IARG_END);
    }
    if (INS_IsBranchOrCall(ins))
    {
        INS_InsertCall(
            ins, IPOINT_TAKEN_BRANCH, (AFUNPTR)LogRegWrite,
            IARG_INST_PTR,
            IARG_UINT32,
            INS_RegW(ins, i),
            IARG_CONTEXT, // to access the register value
            IARG_END);
    }        
}
```

I read [here](https://beta.groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/pinheads/conversations/topics/5444) that

> You can't actually be sure that fs is not zero by looking at the EA, because the value in fs is an index into the table of segment descriptors, not a pointer in its own right... The pointer value is taken from the segment descriptor, but is mirrored in the Pin virtual register REG_SEG_FS_BASE.

I am not sure how to get the value using this virtual register.

Related info from the official manual:

> When IARG_CONTEXT is used in probe mode,it is impossible to get certain register values correct. The values in these registers are meaningless when IARG_CONTEXT is used in probe mode:
> REG_SEG_GS_BASE
> REG_SEG_FS_BASE
> REG_INST_G0 - REG_INST_G19
> Using IARG_RETURN_REGS and IARG_REG_REFERENCE is not supported in Probe mode.

How do I print the value of the fs and gs regsiters after every instruction execution?

Comment: Are you using probe mode (aka hooking)? If not, doesn't this work for you?

  auto reg = PIN_GetContextReg(ctx, REG_SEG_FS);

Comment: Are you on x64 because there you cannot change segment registers.

Answer (score 1):

```
const CONTEXT *ctx; (from the arguments of LogRegWrite...)
PIN_REGISTER regval;
PIN_GetContextRegval(ctx, REG_SEG_GS, reinterpret_cast<UINT8*>(&regval));
PIN_GetContextRegval(ctx, REG_SEG_FS, reinterpret_cast<UINT8*>(&regval));
PIN_GetContextRegval(ctx, REG_SEG_GS_BASE, reinterpret_cast<UINT8*>(&regval));
PIN_GetContextRegval(ctx, REG_SEG_FS_BASE, reinterpret_cast<UINT8*>(&regval));
```

You use use `PIN_GetContextRegval` API to get register value of `fs`/`gs`. As mentioned in a question on the Pinheads Yahoo group [1], `REG_SEG_GS` will only get the value of `fs`/`gs`, in other word, the index to GDT, `REG_SEG_GS_BASE` will get the base address of the corresponding entry of GDT.

[1] https://beta.groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/pinheads/conversations/topics/5444, retrieved through [Wayback machine](https://archive.org/details/yahoo-groups-2017-06-06T08-31-40Z-67aaf3)

> I think you're probably after REG_SEG_FS_BASE, which is the address of the base of the F segment.
>
> > I know fs is not zero by obtaining the memop effective address (0x7ffff7fd4728 in my case).
>
> You can't actually be sure that fs is not zero by looking at the EA, because the value in fs is an index into the table of segment descriptors, not a pointer in its own right...
> The pointer value is taken from the segment descriptor, but is mirrored in the Pin virtual register REG_SEG_FS_BASE.